# how to update the field 'updated_at' of a sequelize model without modifiyng any attributes

Tags: node.js, postgresql, timestamp, sequelize.js

I'm using sequelize 2.0.0 with PostgreSQL. 
**I would like to know if it's possible to update the field 'updated_at' of a model with one method. If yes, how can I achieve that?**

For instance, in others frameworks, like Laravel, you have model.touch() to automatically update the 'updated_at' of a model.

I've already tried to use model.save() but as the sequelize doc says, calling this method without attributes does nothing. Also, in the doc, I didn't find anything that allow me to do what I need to do simply.

Thanks in advance for help.

Edit: 
To give an example of what I'm trying to achieved, I've already had an instance of my model: 
 `Model.findById(1).then(function(myInstance){
     [...]
     myInstance.update() //here, I didn't change any attributes of myInstance and I would like to update the field udpated_at without doing another query.
     [...]
}):`
The question is : How can I update the field updated_at of my previous instance with one method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To update an instance value, you can use [instance.set(key, value, [options])](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/instance/#setkey-value-options).

```
myInstance.set('updatedAt', new Date());
myInstance.save().then(function() {
  // my nice callback stuff
});
```

The [sequelize docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/querying/#basics) have a good example of doing an update query if you don't have an instance:

```
Post.update({
  updatedAt: null,
}, {
  where: {
    deletedAt: {
      $ne: null
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I would like to avoid this query because I've already had an instance of my class. Now I'm trying to do the update with this instance.

Comment: The provided instance method doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: Since you referenced 'updated_at' above instead of 'updatedAt', perhaps you need to reference the correct field. This could also (confusingly be the case) if you have your configuration set to `{ timestamps: true, updatedAt: 'updated_at' }` or something similar. You need to reference the underscored version, not the camel case version.

Comment: ow can we set updatedAt to the database current timestamp? In postgres: 'updated_at = now()'

We don't want to set the date from nodejs (slightly different), also don't want to use db triggers.

Comment: I don't know about PostgreSQL but the following works in MySQL for me: `myInstace.changed('updatedAt', true); myInstance.save();`

Answer (score 0):

My solution is a little hackey. I had to update a field on the instance to be different than what it was supposed to be, so that sequelize thought that the field changed, even if it didn't; and make sure the proper field data was passed in afterwards.

For example, let's say the variable `myInstance` has a field named `title`, and a variable `data` holds the unchanged (or new) title ( `{title:"OLD_OR_NEW_TITLE"}` ). If I add to the code `myInstance.set('title', data.title+'_FAKE')`, then when the update/save method is called ( `myInstance.update(data)` ), sequelize will think that the field has changed, even though it might not have.